# why wont these delete action work? undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to delete an object in rails, it is a child of the job class.

```
%tbody
        -if @job.job_delivery_costs.any?
          -@job.job_delivery_costs.each do |delivery_cost|
            %tr
              %td
                =delivery_cost.timing
              %td
                =delivery_cost.quantity
              %td
                =delivery_cost.cost_per_unit
              %td
                =delivery_cost.quantity * delivery_cost.cost_per_unit
              %td
                =link_to 'Delete', admin_job_job_delivery_cost_path(@job, delivery_cost), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger"
```

routes.rb

```
resources :jobs do
      member do
      resources :job_delivery_costs
      resources :extra_costs, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

controller

```
before_action :get_job

def destroy
    if @job && get_job_delivery_cost
      @get_job_delivery_cost.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Job delivery cost removed"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Couldn't find the record"
    end
    redirect_to admin_job_job_products_path(@job)
  end

  private

    def get_job
        @job = Job.find_by(id: params[:job_id])
    end

    def job_delivery_cost_params
      params.require(:job_delivery_cost).permit!
    end

    def get_job_delivery_cost
        @job_delivery_cost ||= JobDeliveryCost.where(id: params[:id]).first
    end

end


rake routes

rep delivery_cost
                                   job_delivery_costs_new GET    /job_delivery_costs/new(.:format)                                                   job_delivery_costs#new
                                     admin_delivery_costs GET    /admin/delivery_costs(.:format)                                                     admin/delivery_costs#index
                                                          POST   /admin/delivery_costs(.:format)                                                     admin/delivery_costs#create
                                  new_admin_delivery_cost GET    /admin/delivery_costs/new(.:format)                                                 admin/delivery_costs#new
                                 edit_admin_delivery_cost GET    /admin/delivery_costs/:id/edit(.:format)                                            admin/delivery_costs#edit
                                      admin_delivery_cost GET    /admin/delivery_costs/:id(.:format)                                                 admin/delivery_costs#show
                                                          PATCH  /admin/delivery_costs/:id(.:format)                                                 admin/delivery_costs#update
                                                          PUT    /admin/delivery_costs/:id(.:format)                                                 admin/delivery_costs#update
                                                          DELETE /admin/delivery_costs/:id(.:format)                                                 admin/delivery_costs#destroy
                             admin_job_job_delivery_costs GET    /admin/jobs/:job_id/job_delivery_costs(.:format)                                    admin/job_delivery_costs#index
                                                          POST   /admin/jobs/:job_id/job_delivery_costs(.:format)                                    admin/job_delivery_costs#create
                          new_admin_job_job_delivery_cost GET    /admin/jobs/:job_id/job_delivery_costs/new(.:format)                                admin/job_delivery_costs#new
                         edit_admin_job_job_delivery_cost GET    /admin/jobs/:job_id/job_delivery_costs/:id/edit(.:format)                           admin/job_delivery_costs#edit
                              admin_job_job_delivery_cost GET    /admin/jobs/:job_id/job_delivery_costs/:id(.:format)                                admin/job_delivery_costs#show
                                                          PATCH  /admin/jobs/:job_id/job_delivery_costs/:id(.:format)                                admin/job_delivery_costs#update
                                                          PUT    /admin/jobs/:job_id/job_delivery_costs/:id(.:format)                                admin/job_delivery_costs#update
                                                          DELETE /admin/jobs/:job_id/job_delivery_costs/:id(.:format)                                admin/job_delivery_costs#destroy
```

surely I am passing though the right parameters here. and it must be finding the object if it is to get to go through to the destroy condition, otherwise it would just render object not found.

but i get this error

```
if @job 
      @job_delivery_cost ||= JobDeliveryCost.where(id: params[:id]).first
      @get_job_delivery_cost.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Job delivery cost removed"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Couldn't find the record"
    end
    redirect_to admin_job_job_products_path(@job)
```

Comment: Are you sure your link is getting to the destroy action? Do you have the pry gem installed. Try putting a biding.pry inside the `destroy` action to test if the link is going to the right place. It could be a problem with your link.

Comment: sorry the error is from an error debugger, instead of the standard active record thingy magig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the `.destroy` method on the wrong object, call it on the `@job_delivery_cost` object instead:

```
def destroy
  if @job && get_job_delivery_cost
    @job_delivery_cost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Job delivery cost removed"
```

---

**Can I suggest something** for your code? I think it should be a little more consistent, something like the following:

```
def destroy
  set_job_delivery_cost # will set the variable `@job_delivery_cost`
  if @job.present? && @job_delivery_cost.present?
    @job_delivery_cost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Job delivery cost removed"
  else
    flash[:error] = "Couldn't find the record"
  end
  redirect_to admin_job_job_products_path(@job)
end

private

def set_job
  @job = Job.find_by(id: params[:job_id])
end

def set_job_delivery_cost
  @job_delivery_cost ||= JobDeliveryCost.find_by(id: params[:id])
end

def job_delivery_cost_params
  params.require(:job_delivery_cost).permit!
end
```

As you can see, I renamed the methods `get_job` and `get_job_delivery_cost` to `set_job` and `set_job_delivery_cost`. The method itself is saying that its executing provokes the declaration of its variable.

A method `get_job` would be implemented like this, to respect its name:

```
def get_job
  Job.find_by(id: params[:job_id])
end
```

And the usage in the controller would be:

```
def destroy
  @job = get_job
  # etc.
end
```

Comment: but that deletes the entire job, not the instance of the child class, job delivery cost

Comment: that's awesome. again really helpful